# Errors while trying to compile the "Original" Library Source code of JAVA 1.7.0 in eclipes

Tags: java, jvm

sorry for bothering you all ..

I am trying to check out the SDK "Original" source code of sun java 1.7.0 (the src.zip file that come along with the complete package) in eclipse. I wanted to investigate the library src  code for java.io.ObjectInputStream or java.util.ArrayList ....etc

But when I unzip the src.zip file and put it in Eclipse (under a new Java project) it shows me  errors (attaching a snapshot of some errors ) ..Errors occurred during the compiling the source code lib
[image: Errors occurred during the compiling the source code lib.]

I am also attaching some of the errors screen shots ....... Errors in the code [image: Errors in the code]

Please pardon my ignorance and guide me to the correct path.

Many thanks

Regards

Comment: What's the source level set to in your project? What version of Eclipse are we talking about?

Comment: @ beny23 : I am using eclipse helios and I would like to see as far as I cam. But the bare minimum, I like to know if i could compile the Src code given by with the JDK? and if I could how to?

Answer (score 3):

`src.jar` does only contain the source code of the **public APIs** and in certain places those delegate to 'internal' classes, e.g. `com.sun.*`.

If you want to look at the publicly available source code, you just have to install a JDK and point your Eclipse to the JDK instead of the JRE. Then it will automatically link to the source. Example screenshots reference IBM JDK (not JRE) 7 on Ubuntu.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that if you use OpenJDK via `apt` on Ubuntu (your screenshots look like this), you must explicitly install the source:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-source
```

**Workspace preferences:**

[image]

**and source code for java.util.ArrayList**

The icon on the editor tab indicates that this is just a *link* to the source file and not the source itself, you cannot edit it.

[image]

Comment: Hello @home, Thanks fro replying back .. I tried the solution u suggeste, but it did not work.. still getting the errors.

Comment: Hello @home, Thanks fro replying back .. I tried the solution u suggeste, but it did not work.. still getting the errors.

I initially had sun-jdk1.7.0_02. for installation of which I downloaded the Sun-Java JDK, untar/unzip it and copied in /usr/lib/jvm/jdk.x.x and used update-alternative --install/config commands to set Java paths also wrote JAVA_HOME and PATH variable in .bashrc file.

please correct me if i ma doing anything wrong ..